# Let $G$ be a linear algebraic group and $C_G(x)$ be the centralizer of $x$. Show that $C_G(x)$ is a closed subgroup for all $x\in G$.

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-groups, zariski-topology

Let $G$ be a linear algebraic group and $C_G(x)$ be the centralizer of  $x$. Show that $C_G(x)$ is a closed subgroup for all $x\in G$.

I want to enstablish a homomorphism from $G$ to $G$, and the kernel is $C_G(x)$, but I can't find it.

Comment: Your idea won't work, because in general a centralizer is not a normal subgroup.

Comment: Please keep the title as the one I suggested (unless a better one replaces it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g_nx = x g_n$ for all $g_n \in G$. If $g_n \rightarrow g$ then $g_nx \rightarrow gx$ and $x g_n \rightarrow xg$ and since $g_n x = x g_n$, we have that $xg = gx$. Hence $g \in C_G$. Hence $C_G(x)$ is a closed set.

Comment: This does not answer the question in full generality, and so I think it ought to be a comment.  Nobody is saying the field $G$ is over is even algebraically closed, let alone $\Bbb C$.

Comment: I am not using the fact that underlying field is $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Oh, I see; I was just misled by your initial version. Sorry! I have upvoted now.